# list of users that have mentioned the searched user. (Twitter)

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-8, linq-to-twitter

I have a problem when I want to display users that have mentioned the searched user on my application.
I'll explain:

At first when I launch the program I need to allow the application to use my account to allow me doing some search.
After that, I can search twitter users on my application and display some information about him.

The problem is the following, 
when I want to display the users that have mentioned the searched user, it fails!
It just display :
*the users that mentioned me (when I search myself)
*I appear in users that have mentioned the searched user list if I mentioned him recently,

So, the application search mentioned list not with the searched user but with the logged user!
I don't want it.

I m developing the application on c#/XAML and I am using linqToTwitter.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter API for user mentions only operates on behalf of the authenticated user. Therefore, if you wanted the mentions of a user, you would need to have that user's permission to operate on their behalf. i.e. if that user authenticated with Twitter through your application. Then you would have their OAuth tokens, authenticate on their behalf, and perform the query.

Another approach that isn't as reliable is to use the Search API, adding their ScreenName as the Query. You can verify that a Status returned by the search is a valid mention by examining the Status.Entities.UserMentions collection property.

Comment: Can I do that with LinqToTwitter? I think that LinqToTwitter uses REST API of Twitter...

Comment: Search is part of the REST API. LINQ to Twitter supports both REST and Stream APIs.